# Prestashop basic module, small adjusting

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, prestashop

I created file mymodule.php for Prestashop 1.4

```
<?php
if (!defined('_CAN_LOAD_FILES_'))
    exit;

class MyModule extends Module
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = "mymodule";
        $this->version = "1.0";
        $this->author = "Tomtop";
        $this->tab = "front_office_features";

        $this->_postErrors = array();

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l("My Module Name");
        $this->description = $this->l("This is my module description.");
    }

    protected function setConfig($key,$value)
    {
        return Configuration::updateValue($this->name.$key,$value,true);
    }

    protected function getConfig($value)
    {
        return Configuration::get($this->name.$value);
    }

    protected function deleteConfig($value)
    {
        return Configuration::deleteByName($this->name.$value);
    }

    function install()
    {
        if (!parent::install()
            OR !$this->registerHook('home')
            OR !$this->registerHook('footer')
        )
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        parent::uninstall();

        return true;
    }


    public function hookHome($params)
    {       

    }

    public function hookfooter($params)
    {       

    }


    private function _postProcess()
    {
        $this->_html .= '<div class="conf confirm">'.$this->l("Updated")."</div>";
    }

    public function getContent()
    {
        $this->_html .= "<h2>".$this->displayName."</h2>";

        if (Tools::isSubmit("submit"))
        {   
            $this->_postProcess();
        }

        $this->_displayForm();

        return $this->_html;
    }   

    private function _displayForm()
    {   
        $this->_html .= '<form action="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'" method="post">

            <fieldset>
                <legend><img src="../modules/scroller/logo.gif" alt="" class="middle" />'.$this->l('Settings').'</legend>

                <br />
                <center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="'.$this->l('Upgrade').'" class="button" /></center>
            </fieldset> 
        </form>';
    }
}
```

Where in above code should be added mymodule.tpl template, which contain main html code, i.e.

`return $this->display(__FILE__, 'mymodule.tpl');`

Also, in which place in mymodule.php to add js and css files that are linked in head tag like this:

```
public function hookHeader()
{
    Tools::addJS($this->_path.'js/myjscript1.js');
    Tools::addJS($this->_path.'js/myjscript2.js');
    Tools::addCSS($this->_path.'css/mymodule.css', 'all');
}
```

And where should be added `global $smarty;` if it required in above code?

Answer (score 0):

The `hookHeader` should be declared in the `install` method.

You should reference `global $smarty` at the beginning of each class method that needs to use `$smarty`.

That means that in the methods where you'll be using `$this->display()` to render a .tpl you should also add the `global $smarty` to be able to use the `$smarty->assign()` method.

Comment: Hooks are not necessarily connected to visual sections where you want to show content. They are used in many situations for example an imaginary `hookProductUpdate` will be called when any product is changed so that you can send email messages to clients saying "wow the prices have been changed for product X".

Comment: I think *drop-in* solutions are a bad way to learn. Understanding and doing it yourself is best. If it's way over your head you should be learning the basics not diving into the deep end and if it's not way over your head you'll manage to understand and do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Anything returned by the functions hookHome() and hookFooter() will be displayed when the hook points are rendered. Ignoring smarty to begin with you can just do something like:

```
public function hookHome($params)
{
  return "<h2>Wow, my module displays something</h2>";
}
```

You may of course want to use a template file with your module -- **although you don't have to**. If you are going to use a smarty template then you can declare a global instance within the hook functions.

```
public function hookHome($params)
{
  global $smarty;
  ...
  ...
```

As noted in Mihai's answer you will also have to modify the install function should you want to insert the css and js using the "header" hook:

```
function install()
{
    if (!parent::install()
        OR !$this->registerHook('home')
        OR !$this->registerHook('footer')
        OR !$this->registerHook('header')
    )
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The code above is fine, but if you're not assigning any variables for smarty to use, then adding a template is unnecessary (and will slow down page rendering slightly due to the smarty overhead). The only other advantage of using a template file is that it can be overridden in the theme so someone else can modify it, but whether that's something anyone would do is down to your module.